# shc on Mac showing 'Killed: 9' error

Tags: macos, bash, encryption, binary, strip

I'm using [shc](http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/~frosal/sources/) on Mac OS, to generate stripped binary of bash scripts, for distribution. The issue is, when i execute the stripped binary (with `.x` ext) it shows the error `killed: 9`.

Even when i `make` and `make test` (as shown [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/encrypt-bash-shell-script/)), it strips the dummy match script and generates match.x, which when executed, gives the same `killed: 9` error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should check this http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/123109-shc-compiler-error-aix.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it working. Just had to do

```
shc -T -f test.sh
```

I was trying it without the `-T`